# check if TouchableOpacity is still clicked in while loop React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, while-loop, native, touchableopacity

is it possible to check if TouchableOpacity is still clicked in a while loop whith React Native and javascript

> i tried doing with onPressOut that it changes a var